# Rename main scss file via gulp-rename

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass

I have a `scss` folder I'm watching. I'm including all partials into `main.scss` and I'd like the generated file to be named `style.css`

Below is a portion of my `gulpfile.js`

```
const rename = require("gulp-rename");

const files = {
  scssPath: './src/scss/**/*.scss',
  jsPath: 'src/js/**/*.js'
}

function scssTask() {
  return src(files.scssPath)
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(rename('style.css'))
    .pipe(postcss([ autoprefixer(), cssnano()]))
    .pipe(dest('web/assets/css'));
}

// default
exports.default = series(
  parallel(scssTask, jsTask),
  watchTask
);
```

The `rename` part doesn't seem to have any affect. The file gets generated into `main.css`

Sure, I could just rename my `main.scss` to `style.scss`, but I like having "main" for the sass files and "style" for the generated file the browser will use

Also, here's my `main.scss` file:

```
@import 'utilities/variables';

@import 'base/normalize';
@import 'base/typography';
```

Comment: Do you have multiple files here: `'./src/scss/**/*.scss'`?  How about if you just change that to the `main.scss` path?  That is all you need if `main.scss` includes everything else you need.

Comment: @Mark, I do have other files and if I were only to watch the `main.scss` file, then it would not listen to the other files being saved. I'd have to open main and then save that

Comment: Your watchTask can be watching multiple `scss` files but all files run through `scssTask` will be renamed `style.css` (unless they are all partials other than `main.scss`) so you would only see the last non-partial run through `scssTask` end up in `style.scss`.    So is `main.scss` the only non-partial you are watching and running through `scssTask`?  If yes, change to `return src(path_to_main.scss-only)`.

Comment: If you are running more non-partials, other than main.scss, they will all be renamed to `style.scss` and thus only the last one through the task will be reflected in the final `style.scss`.